# Simuator selection shortcut not visible

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

[image]

I have attached a screenshot of the problem.

I am able to select the device using the product menu but there is no shortcut visible in the toolbar to select the device.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View/Show Toolbar and click it.

Answer (score 0):

Just Restart Xcode. Same problem i have faced Xcode Restart resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before.  The issue in my case was that the run destinations list would disappear if the window was too narrow.  If you resize the window to be wider, it should pop back in.